# Multiple Container DIVs Changing Content Independently via Links

Tags: jquery, html

On my website I have various containers with content `<div>`s text in them.  I then have links in the container  which change the content `<div>`s.

However, I cannot get the links to target a specific content , instead the both sets of links change both container `<div>`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/1/

If you look at the jfiddle, I want both the first-div and the second-div  to have content in them automatically, and then I would like the links to only change their respective content.  Instead I only have content1-4 showing up in both.  I'll put the code here as well:

```
//HTML
<div class="container-div">
    <div id="tab">
    <ul>
        <li id="tab1" class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li id="tab2"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li id="tab3"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li id="tab4"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content1" class="content">Content Here1</div>
    <div id="content2" class="content">Content Here2</div>
    <div id="content3" class="content">Content Here3</div>
    <div id="content4" class="content">Content Here4</div>
</div>


<div class="container-div">
    <div id="tab">
    <ul>
        <li id="tab5" class="active"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li id="tab6"><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li id="tab7"><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
        <li id="tab8"><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content5" class="content">Content Here1</div>
    <div id="content6" class="content">Content Here2</div>
    <div id="content7" class="content">Content Here3</div>
    <div id="content8" class="content">Content Here4</div>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
//Jquery Business

$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeId = $(".active").attr("id").replace("tab",""); $("#content" + activeId).show();
   $("#tab a").click(function() {
      $(".content").hide();
      $("#tab .active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active")
      var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").replace("tab","");
      $("#content" + id).show();
   });

});
```

Comment: i'm a little confused as to what you want to do. you want when you click on an li to fill it with the corresponding content from a div?

Comment: You cant have two DIVs with the same ID.

Comment: I am aware of the id issue, the thing is the script that I have only works with one container div.  If I attempt to use this to make another container div, it simply does not work.

As of right now, if I just use one container div with the id "tab" then it works fine, but I want to have multiple containers (up to 6) and I do not know how to manipulate the script in order for it to work independently on each container.

Comment: give the containers different ids, then use classes or another attr on your child elements.  then you can select what you need based on the container id, and manipulate the children based on an attribute or class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/24/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems. First, you have two `div` tags with `id="tab"`. Your other problem is that you have `class="active"` on two `li` tags at the same time. I'm working with your code now to see if I can find a solution.

**Update:** Here's a link to a forked fiddle where it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/LNXPG/ FYI, you have content 1-4 showing up on both because of your HTML...

`<div id="content1" class="content">Content Here1

<div id="content2" class="content">Content Here2

<div id="content3" class="content">Content Here3

<div id="content4" class="content">Content Here4`

That code is repeated twice, once for the first set of tabs and again for the second. If you change 1,2,3,4 to 5,6,7,8 for the second set it displays properly.

Comment: In terms of showing the content this works great.  However, what I am looking to do is to have them display content independently.

That is, if I click link 5, to display content 5, I still want the content in the first container div to be showing at the same time.

Thanks for your help.